# Bind failed with Invalid argument error

Tags: sockets, bind

I'm trying to write a simple program which uses bind. The code compiles on solaris, but I get a bind() failed with Invalid Argument error.

I have tried many times but getting the same error, I'm unable to figure out the error.

Here is the code :

```
int my_func ()
{
    struct sockaddr_storage name;
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    int status;

    char hostnamestr[256];
    gethostname (hostnamestr, 256);

    int iRC;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));

    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ((status = getaddrinfo(hostnamestr, NULL, &hints, &res) != 0))
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        return 1;
    }

    memcpy(&name, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
    freeaddrinfo(res);
    monsocket = socket (name.ss_family, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    int iLastError = WSAGetLastError ();

    if (monsocket == -1)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "cannot open socket for monitors [%s]\n", wsaerror (iLastError));
        return 1;
    }

    sockopts(monsocket);  
    int flags;
    flags = fcntl (monsocket, F_GETFL);
    iLastError = WSAGetLastError ();

    if (flags < 0)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "cannot get flags for socket [%s]\n", wsaerror (iLastError));
        return 1;
    }

    iRC = fcntl (monsocket, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
    iLastError = WSAGetLastError ();

    if (iRC == -1)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "cannot set flags for socket [%s]\n", wsaerror (iLastError));
        return 1;
    }

    int iPort;
    if(name.ss_family == AF_INET)
    {
        ((struct sockaddr_in *) &name)->sin_port = htons (8091);
    }    
    else if(name.ss_family == AF_INET6)
    {
        ((struct sockaddr_in6 *) &name)->sin6_port = htons (8091);
    }

    struct  sockaddr_in* ipv = (struct sockaddr_in *) &name;
    printf("connecting to addr: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ipv->sin_addr));

    iRC = bind (monsocket, (struct sockaddr *) &name, sizeof (name));
    iLastError = WSAGetLastError ();

    if (iRC == -1)
    {
        close(monsocket);
        monsocket=-1;
        fprintf (stderr, "could not bind to port %d\n", iPort);
        printf("Error %s",wsaerror (iLastError));
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf (SCHED_SHOW_MSG, "bound on port %i\n", ntohs (iPort));
    }
    iRC = listen (monsocket, SOMAXCONN);
    iLastError = WSAGetLastError ();

    if (iRC == -1)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "could not listen to socket [%s]\n", wsaerror (iLastError));
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Same error, but for me, the issue was here `if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&si_here, sizeof(sockaddr) == -1))
                die("bind");`
Ultimate stupidity. Can you spot it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> bind (monsocket, (struct sockaddr *) &name, sizeof (name))
> ```

Your `sizeof(name)` yields the size of the generic `sockaddr_storage` size. You need the size of `sockaddr_in` or `sockaddr_in6`.

In any case, you'd be better of **by just using the stuff from `getaddrinfo` directly**:

```
monsocket = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
bind(monsocket, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
```

In order to do that you'll have to move your `freeaddrinfo(res)` call.

Comment: Thank you, sizeof(sockaddr_in or sockaddr_in6) works fine.           How to give port number if I use                       bind(monsocket, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);

Comment: @Naga You can specify the port in `getaddrinfo` (second argument).

Answer (score 0):

i got same error. and later found that i created socket for AF_INET and was trying to bind using IPv6 address.